# Get my Apps Data iTunes Connect

Tags: php, mysql, applescript, app-store-connect

I'm looking for a script or series of scripts that download and parse iTunes Connect sales data and AppStore comments, ratings and rankings data for a defined app. I want to get my apps data on my web site .

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by making following request in PHP

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id={YOUR_APP_ID}&entity=software");
```

For Example:

```
$response = file_get_contents("https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=317469184&entity=software");
```

Will give following JSON output:

```
    {
     "resultCount":1,
    "results": [
        {
            "kind":"software", "features":[], 
            "supportedDevices":["iPad23G", "iPhone5s", "iPad2Wifi", "iPhone5c", "iPadThirdGen", "iPadFourthGen4G", "iPhone4", "iPadMini", "iPadThirdGen4G", "iPadFourthGen", "iPhone5", "iPodTouchFifthGen", "iPadMini4G", "iPhone4S"], 
            "isGameCenterEnabled":false, 
            "screenshotUrls":["http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/25/c1/45/25c145d7-5272-4f41-536f-c5744cd0c61e/screen1136x1136.jpeg", "http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/61/3c/0c/613c0c2e-1263-c54c-8658-2de8e6a0dd4b/screen1136x1136.jpeg", "http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/fa/19/ad/fa19ad92-85cc-c4bf-921b-f575a543327c/screen1136x1136.jpeg", "http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple4/v4/3d/5d/97/3d5d9701-f6d9-cc12-7e91-b9ede19e9776/screen1136x1136.jpeg", "http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple6/v4/52/cc/ee/52cceed3-5837-9987-4c10-7cd02bf33b1e/screen1136x1136.jpeg"], "ipadScreenshotUrls":[], "artworkUrl60":"http://a1156.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple2/v4/54/93/ac/5493acfd-1a6e-7960-dda5-7de005232d35/AppIcon57x57.png", "artworkUrl512":"http://a1105.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple4/v4/95/77/8b/95778b7e-8897-3b68-b8f9-134f34531b25/mzl.sobbgbbg.png", "artistViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/espn/id317469187?uo=4", "artistId":317469187, "artistName":"ESPN", "price":0.00, "version":"4.0.5", 
            "description":"Introducing the all-new SportsCenter app, a supercharged update to the popular ScoreCenter app packed with live scores, breaking news, video highlights, in-depth analysis, personalized alerts and more. What more could any sports fan ask for?  \n\nFeatures include: \n- Instant scores and updates on the biggest games of the day as well as your favorite teams \n- Breaking news and analysis across hundreds of leagues and teams, all powered by ESPN's authoritative newsroom \n- Dozens of notification options: never miss another kickoff, scoring play, substitution, final whistle or tidbit of breaking news \n- Add, edit and remove favorite teams quickly and easily for a customized experience throughout \n- Deep Twitter integration for a social perspective on news, rumors and gossip", "currency":"USD", "genres":["Sports", "Entertainment"], "genreIds":["6004", "6016"], "releaseDate":"2009-06-02T07:00:00Z", "sellerName":"ESPN Inc.", "bundleId":"com.espn.ScoreCenter", "trackId":317469184, "trackName":"ESPN SportsCenter", "primaryGenreName":"Sports", "primaryGenreId":6004, 
            "releaseNotes":"- In-game highlights added to game pages during the Live game\n- SportsCenter TV Graphics now inside the app\n- Support for World Cup videos and games\n- Easily share video right from the News Feed\n- Improved performance \n- Enhanced design\n- The latest Breaking News", "minimumOsVersion":"7.0", "formattedPrice":"Free", "wrapperType":"software", "trackCensoredName":"ESPN SportsCenter", "languageCodesISO2A":["NB", "DA", "NL", "EN", "FR", "DE", "IT", "NN", "ES"], "fileSizeBytes":"18953341", "sellerUrl":"http://www.espn.com", "contentAdvisoryRating":"4+", "averageUserRatingForCurrentVersion":3.5, "userRatingCountForCurrentVersion":4317, "artworkUrl100":"http://a1105.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple4/v4/95/77/8b/95778b7e-8897-3b68-b8f9-134f34531b25/mzl.sobbgbbg.png", "trackViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/espn-sportscenter/id317469184?mt=8&uo=4", "trackContentRating":"4+", "averageUserRating":3.5, "userRatingCount":264216
        }
    ]
}
```

[**Reference Link**](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#searching)

Comment: This is public data, I need private data , i want to allow user to give my website his/her username and password of iTunes. Than my system will auto search his/her apps from itnues account and list them his dash boad.

Comment: check reference provided in bottom, there is also info how to search apps, it is same instead of lookup you need to use search

Comment: Thanks for you reply Patel, But i can't use this . because first i want to get the app ids of the user  who is providing me itunes username and password .